# Fix FutureWarning related to the pandas append function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, future-warning

I am getting the following FutureWarning in my Python code:

FutureWarning: The frame.append method is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.concat instead.

Right now I was using the append function, in various parts of my code, to add rows to an existing DataFrame.

Example 1:

```
init_hour = pd.to_datetime('00:00:00')
orig_hour = init_hour+timedelta(days=1)
while init_hour < orig_hour:
   row = {'Hours': init_hour.time()}
   df = df.append(row, ignore_index = True)
   init_hour = init_hour + timedelta(minutes=60)
```

Example 2:

```
row2 = {'date': tmp_date, 'false_negatives': fn, 'total': total}
df2 = df2.append(row2, ignore_index = True)
```

How could I solve this in a simple way without modifying much of the code before the sections above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `pd.concat` instead of append. Preferably on a bunch of rows at the same time. Also, use date_range and timedelta_range whenever possible.

Example 1:

```
# First transformation

init_hour = pd.to_datetime('00:00:00')
orig_hour = init_hour+timedelta(days=1)
rows = []
while init_hour < orig_hour:
   rows.append({'Hours': init_hour.time()})
   init_hour = init_hour + timedelta(minutes=60)


df = pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(rows)], axis=0, ignore_index=True)
```

```
# Second transformation - just construct it without loop
hours = pd.Series(pd.date_range("00:00:00", periods=24, freq="H").time, name="Hours")

# Then insert/concat hours into your dataframe.
```

Example 2

Don't see the context so it's harder to know what's appropriate.
Either of these two

```
# Alternative 1
row2 = {'date': tmp_date, 'false_negatives': fn, 'total': total}
row2df = pd.DataFrame.from_records([row2])
df2 = pd.concat([df2, row2df], ignore_index=True, axis=0)  # how to handle index depends on context

# Alternative 2
# assuming integer monotonic index - assign a new row with loc
new_index = len(df2.index)
df2.loc[new_index] = row2
```

Note: there's a reason append is deprecated. Using it row by row leads to very slow code. So it's important that we do **more than just a local translation of the code** to not waste computer time when the analysis runs.

Pandas authors are trying to get us to understand and appreciate concatenating or building dataframes using more efficient means, i.e. not row-by-row. Combining many rows into one DataFrame and concatenating bigger dataframes together is the way to go.